# Grouping with no repeating values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have the following data:

```
+-----+-----+
| ID1 | ID2 |
+-----+-----+
| 100 | AAA |
| 100 | BBB |
| 200 | AAA |
| 200 | BBB |
| 300 | AAA |
| 300 | BBB |
| 300 | CCC |
| 400 | BBB |
+-----+-----+
```

I need to somehow group the rows in table above and get:

```
+-----+-----+      +-----+-----+      +-----+-----+
| ID1 | ID2 |      | ID1 | ID2 |      | ID1 | ID2 |
+-----+-----+      +-----+-----+      +-----+-----+
| 100 | AAA |  OR  | 100 | BBB |  OR  | 400 | BBB | IS ACCEPTABLE
| 200 | BBB |      | 200 | AAA |      | 300 | CCC |
| 300 | CCC |      | 300 | CCC |      | 200 | AAA |
+-----+-----+      +-----+-----+      +-----+-----+
```

Which of the above given grouped result-set I get is not important just as long **there are no repeating occurrences of both ID1 and ID2 values**. I.e. following result-set (got by simple grouping by ID1 or by ID2) would be "wrong":

```
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
| ID1 | ID2 |       | ID1 | ID2 |
+-----+-----+       +-----+-----+
| 100 | AAA |  AND  | 100 | AAA | ARE BOTH "WRONG"
| 200 | AAA |       | 100 | BBB |
| 300 | AAA |       | 300 | CCC |
| 400 | BBB |       +-----+-----+
+-----+-----+
```

Not to forget an important fact. I am bound to using MySQL functions.

Comment: The fact that it's unimportant which of the 3 results is returned, is sometimes suggestive of a more fundamental problem with your data model. Just sayin'

Comment: @Strawberry, I agree that sometimes it could be but in this case it's not. I tried to generalize the data example as much as possible so it's not related to a specific business logic problem. Let's say all exclusive combinations of ID1 and ID2 have the absolutely the same "weight". Most trivial real-life example would be people coupling where input table has all acceptable matches according to some criteria. Output table has only one condition - one person can not be a part of two couples. If all your acceptable pairings are already 'taken" then you end up with no pair.

Comment: I guess this is a question about permutations (or possibly comnbinations)

Comment: This is not an NP-complete problem, so there *could* be a reasonable solution in SQL (although I doubt it).  I would suggest that you start by understanding bipartite graphs and matching problems.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)

Comment: What about 100(AAA),300(CCC),400(BBB) ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, to be honest, terms you mentioned are not familiar to me but additional theoretic knowledge is always welcome. Thanks. Hopefully it will lead me to the answer.

Comment: @Strawberry, last combination would also be acceptable solution to my problem. Simplicity of the solution (i.e. the execution time to be more precise) is the only criteria i have additional to non repeating column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one idea - but I'm not certain that (my)sql is the best tool for combinatorial problems...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id1 INT NOT NULL,id2 CHAR(3) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id1,id2));

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (100 ,'AAA'),
 (100 ,'BBB'),
 (200 ,'AAA'),
 (200 ,'BBB'),
 (300 ,'AAA'),
 (300 ,'BBB'),
 (300 ,'CCC'),
 (400 ,'BBB');

 SELECT *
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.id1 > x.id1 
    AND y.id2 <> x.id2 
   JOIN my_table z 
     ON z.id1 > y.id1 
    AND z.id2 <> x.id2 
    AND z.id2 <> y.id2 
  ORDER 
     BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 | id1 | id2 | id1 | id2 | id1 | id2 |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 | 200 | AAA | 300 | CCC | 400 | BBB |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

BTW, if it matters, this can be reformatted as follows:

```
 SELECT a.*
   FROM my_table a
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT x.id1 x_id1
             , x.id2 x_id2
             , y.id1 y_id1
             , y.id2 y_id2
             , z.id1 z_id1
             , z.id2 z_id2
          FROM my_table x 
          JOIN my_table y 
            ON y.id1 > x.id1 
           AND y.id2 <> x.id2 
          JOIN my_table z 
            ON z.id1 > y.id1 
           AND z.id2 <> x.id2 
           AND z.id2 <> y.id2 
         ORDER 
            BY RAND() LIMIT 1
      ) b
     ON (a.id1,a.id2) IN((x_id1,x_id2),(y_id1,y_id2),(z_id1,z_id2));
```

(E.g.:)

```
+-----+-----+
| id1 | id2 |
+-----+-----+
| 100 | AAA |
| 200 | BBB |
| 300 | CCC |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, it does what I wanted for the given example. Unfortunatelly, adding more rows to to "input table" would require changes in the query. You said one more thing right - SQL is definitely not the best way to go here so I will turn to  some data manipulation on the application level.